# Make Oozie do not change CLASSPATH of java action

Tags: oozie

I'm running java application in oozie and oozie adding something to classpath. How do I know? When I run this application without oozie it works perfectly fine, but with oozie I get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.util.WebAppUtils.getProxyHostsAndPortsForAmFilter(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Ljava/util/List;
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmFilterInitializer.initFilter(AmFilterInitializer.java:40)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.<init>(HttpServer.java:272)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder$2.<init>(WebApps.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.client.MRClientService.serviceStart(MRClientService.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceStart(MRAppMaster.java:1058)
```

I even configured

```
    <property>
        <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
```

But it doesn't help. How I can tell oozie to totally **** off my classpath?

Comment: What kind of Action are you using?

Comment: AFAIK, with a `MapReduce` action Oozie just submits the job as-is, and it inherits the default CLASSPATH set for YARN containers (plus extra application JARs last, or first if you request it). But all other actions require an Oozie **Launcher** JAR (and its dependencies) to bootstrap the execution inside the YARN container. From YARN point of view, there is no difference between Oozie JARs and your custom JARs, they are all "application" JARs, you cannot request a specific order e.g. your JARs then Oozie JARs then Hadoop default CLASSPATH.

Comment: So if the Oozie Launcher ships with some libs that conflict with your application libs *(say, `httpcore`)* then you will get random errors, because the resulting CLASSPATH will randomly put recent libs before older libs, or vice-versa. I've been there.

Comment: Option 1: create a new version of Oozie ShareLibs (especially the common `/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_*/oozie/ ` stub) with the "correct" version of all JARs that generate a conflict, and always request "classpath.first". Option 2: always run Shell actions, and run another JVM inside the shell with the exact CLASSPATH that you want.